# Webstorm does not refresh corrected code

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I am using Webstorm for a Typescript project. It does not remove the red flags (or code highlighted in red) even after I've corrected the error that's causing it. The error continues to show. I suppose, Webstorm does not recompile the project everytime a file is changed - to see if the error is still there. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If the flags are not removed after saving the file, I'd suggest opening a ticket with JetBrains. You'd need to provide specific steps to replicate the problem unlike you've done here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might help to try forcing the File Watcher to run.

Select a project root folder, hit Ctrl+Shift+A -> Ctrl+Shift+A to enable non-menu actions -> type "run file " -> choose Run File Watchers....

This was part of an answer to another question.([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26779818/1757491) by user [Lena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena))

Comment: This was an Awesome Help for me! Thank you!!

Answer (score 7):

Click `TypeScript` button at the bottom right of Webstorm. Then click the `Restart TypeScript Service`

Version: WebStorm 2022.3.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Try File/Invalidate caches, Restart. If it doesn't help, file an issue to youtrack (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB), provideing your idea.log and steps to recreate