# How to get .js and .js.map files rolling to be sub files under .ts file

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I had a bunch of .js and .js.map files that weren't rolled up under there associated .ts files which made it a lot harder find the files I was interested in.

[image: This is what I was seeing]

Before using Webstorm I tried Eclipse and [TypEcs plugin](https://bitbucket.org/axmor/typecs/wiki/Home) on this project (which I think is what led to my issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grouping relations are established when running file watchers and stored in caches. They are lost as a result of caches invalidating/upgrading to different version/etc. To restore them, you need to re-run watchers for your project: select a project root folder, hit Ctrl+Shift+A -> Ctrl+Shift+A to enable non-menu actions -> type "run file " -> choose Run File Watchers.... You can assign custom shortcut for "Plugins | File Watchers | Run File Watchers" action in Settings | Keymap to make this procedure less complicated.
There is a ticket ([WEB-7635](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7635)) that requires maintaining nesting according to watcher settings, so that the relationships are auto-established based on watcher settings, without a need to rebuild everything.

Comment: Thanks for the info I did upgrade from version 8 to 9 as well.

Answer (score 0):

To fix I needed to open NewOld.ts and add a variable and then delete it which I assume kicks off the .ts watcher which corrects the issue.  After running you can see the files are now nested:
[image: Fixed]

Comment: An easier way is to select the file (or directory) in the project's file tree and use `Help -> Find Action` or `Ctrl+Shift+A` (on my keyboard), then choose `Run File Watchers`